# Erro ao enviar email com JavaMail

Tags: java, envio-de-email, javamail

Estava funcionando normalmente. Agora quando rodo o programa aparece o seguinte erro:

```
    Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
```

Esse é o meu metodo

```
public void enviaEmail() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                            "xxxxx@gmail.com", "1111111");
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("xxxxx@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Novo Cadastro efetuado na Ouvidoria!!!");
        message.setText("Nome do Beneficiário: ," + "" + nome);
        System.out.println("Nome email:"+nome);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Você continua com conectividade com o servidor smtp do gmail? Em seu cmd, tente `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`, se ele não conseguir abrir a conexão (não aparecer uma tela toda preta), é um indício de que você passou a ter uma restrição de rede. Além disso, alguem mudou a senha ou as configurações de smtp da conta de e-mail?

Comment: Não abre nada, fala que o telnet não é reconhecido como um comando interno

Comment: Habilite o telnet no Windows: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/910.windows-7-enabling-telnet-client.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Retirado desta pergunta do SO em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378133/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-smtp-gmail-com-port-465-response-1

Você precisa dizer a ele que você está usando SSL:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Abaixo um código fonte em funcionamento:

```
String  d_email = "address@gmail.com",
        d_uname = "Name",
        d_password = "urpassword",
        d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        d_port  = "465",
        m_to = "toAddress@gmail.com",
        m_subject = "Indoors Readable File: " + params[0].getName(),
        m_text = "This message is from Indoor Positioning App. Required file(s) are attached.";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
session.setDebug(true);

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
try {
    msg.setSubject(m_subject);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
            transport.connect(d_host, Integer.valueOf(d_port), d_uname, d_password);
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Mas ja estou dizendo que estou usando: `props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); `

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, você tentou utilizar o código que postei? E o seu antivirus não tem a opção de bloqueio? Já tive vários problemas assim e era o antivírus (normalmente o Avast)

Answer (score 1):

Troque :

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

Para:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
```